# Magento 2.1 Changing review list position in product page

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, custom, product-view, review

I am building a custom theme in magento2.1. In product details page, I need to show customer review list after the review form. By default the list of recent reviews will come first in tab panel followed by review form. I need to show review form first. I have copied
 **vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

and pasted in

**app/design/frontend/custom/theme/Magento_Review/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

and added

```
<referenceBlock element="product.info.product_additional_data" after="product.review.form"/>
```

before closing the body tag. But not affecting in my site. Am I doing right? Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the below file in your custom theme:
`vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/review.phtml`

and change calling the `childHtml` function position:

**from**

```
<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review"></div>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

**to**

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>   
<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review"></div>
```

Comment: I have hided the review tab from product page .But i need to show only the customer reviews in product page before footer section, Can have any idea to solve my issue